# Conformal maps onto open right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, conformal-geometry

On the Big Rudin there is the conformal map

$$\varphi(z) = \frac {1+z}{1-z}$$

which sends $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ to $\{0, 1, \infty\}$.

The book says:

> The segment $(-1, 1)$ maps onto the positive real axis. The unit
>   circle $T$ passes through $-1$ and $1$, hence $\varphi(T)$ is a
>   straight line passing through $\varphi(-1) = 0$. Since $T$ makes a
>   right angle in $-1$ with the real axis, $\varphi(T)$ is the imaginary
>   axis.

Up until now it's clear.

But then he says:

> Since $\varphi(0) = 1$, it follows that $\varphi$ is a conformal
>   one-to-one mapping of the open unit disc onto the open right half
>   plane.

I lost him. Why does all that implies that $\varphi$ maps onto the open right half plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\varphi$ is a Möbius transformation it sends circles onto circles. **The Orientation Principle** (see Chapter III, 3.21 p.53 on *John Conway: Functions of one complex variable I. Second edition*) states that if $\varphi$ maps the circle $C_1$ onto the circle $C_2$ then everything on one side of $C_2$ must be send exclusively to only one side of $C_2$ (the sides depend on the orientation given).

In this case, we have that the unit circle $T$ is sent onto the imaginary axis (which is a circle on the Riemann Sphere), thus the imaginary axis is the boundary of $\varphi(T)$, that is everything on the inside of $T$ must be send only to the left side or only to the right side of the imaginary axis.

To check what side (that is to check what orientation is taken), we only need to check where $\varphi$ sends any point inside $T$. Then since a point inside the unit circle $T$, in this case $0$ is sent to a point on the right half plane $\varphi(0)=1$, we get that $\varphi(T)$ must be the right half plane.

As a corollary we get that $\varphi(\mathbb{C} \setminus T)$ is the left half plane, and you an check it for example by computing $\varphi(2)=-3$

Comment: Ah I see thanks! And why do Mobius transform send boundaries on boundaries? I looked at the wikipedia article and there seems to be nothing about it :-)

Comment: Perhaps boundaries was a strong word. However, is well known that a Möbius transformation take circles onto circles. In the Riemann Sphere a straight line as the imaginary axis is of course a circle. Since $T$ is conformal the orientation principle states that if $T$ take the circle $C_1$ onto the circle $C_2$ everything on the right of  $C_1$ is mapped onto the right of $C_2$ if the orientation is positive or onto the left of $C_2$ if negative. I'll put an edit to be more clear about it. @Ant

Comment: @Ant I have now edited my answer. I hope it is clearer, let me know if it is not.

Comment: yes, much better! Thank you :-)

Comment: You are welcome!! Glad to help